# Python. Внедрение Scrollbar в Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, scrollbar

Есть подобие Paint'а. Умеет рисовать, импортировать картинки, сохранять сделанное и тд. Беда в том, что если на холсте слишком большое изображение, то оно просто не помещается на экране и из-за отсутствия какого-либо средства прокрутки увидеть полностью всё невозможно. Поставил себе цель внедрить `Scrollbar`, чтобы он появлялся, если изображение на холсте выходит за рамки окна. Перечитал десятки постов на разных сайтах и stackoverflow в том числе, но никак не получается внедрить именно в свой проект. Понимаю, что это не сложно, но пробелы в ООП дают о себе знать. Прикрепляю ниже свой код. Надеюсь, что его количество не отпугнет людей, птмч на самом деле там много всего не относящегося к вопросу, а суть понятна благодаря моим комментам. Я закомментил там код, где я пытался добавить `Scrollbar`. На самом деле я буду рад даже если скинете какую-либо документацию, в которой можно почитать как правильно в такой ситуации нужно добавлять такие элементы, ибо на своём курсе программирования слегка упустил этот момент. Однако, искренне буду благодарен решению. Заранее спасибо за ответы.

---

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.tix import *
#import os
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageGrab
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfile


class Paint(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        print(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.color = "black"
        self.brush_size = 2

        self.setUI()

    def set_color(self, new_color):
        self.color = new_color

    def set_brush_size(self, new_size):
        self.brush_size = new_size

    def draw(self, event):
        self.canv.create_oval(event.x - self.brush_size,
                                event.y - self.brush_size,
                                event.x + self.brush_size,
                                event.y + self.brush_size,
                                fill=self.color, outline=self.color)
        # Непосредственно функция, которая будет отвечать за
        # появление "линии" на холсте

    def setScroll(self):
        sw = ScrolledWindow(self, scrollbar=Y)
        sw.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    def setUI(self):
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        # Размещаем активные элементы на родительском окне

        self.columnconfigure(6, weight=1)
        # Даем седьмому столбцу возможность растягиваться, благодаря
        # чему кнопки не будут разъезжаться при ресайзе

        self.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        # То же самое для третьего ряда

        # sw = ScrolledWindow(self, scrollbar=Y)
        # sw.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        # Здесь я как раз и пытался внедрить скролбар, но получал ошибку, связанную
        # с тем, что не могу спаковать то, что спаковано (как я понял)

        self.canv = Canvas(self, bg='white')
        # Создаем поле для рисования, устанавливаем белый фон

        self.canv.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=7, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=E + W + S + N)
        # Прикрепляем канвас методом grid. Он будет находится в 3м ряду, первой колонке,
        # и будет занимать 7 колонок, задаем отступы по X и Y в 5 пикселей, и заставляем
        # растягиваться при растягивании всего окна

        self.canv.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.draw)
        # Привязываем обработчик к канвасу. <B1-Motion> означает "при движении
        # зажатой левой кнопки мыши" вызывать функцию draw

        color_lab = Label(self, text="Цвет кисти: ")
        # Создаем метку для кнопок изменения цвета кисти

        color_lab.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=6)
        # Устанавливаем созданную метку в первый ряд и
        # первую колонку, задаем горизонтальный отступ в 6 пикселей

        red_btn = Button(self, text="Красный", width=8,command=lambda: self.set_color("red"))
        # Создание кнопки:  Установка текста кнопки, задание ширины
        # кнопки (10 символов), функция вызываемая при нажатии кнопки.

        red_btn.grid(row=0, column=1)
        # Устанавливаем кнопку

        # Создание остальных кнопок повторяет ту же логику, что и создание
        # кнопки установки красного цвета, отличаются лишь аргументы.

        green_btn = Button(self, text="Зеленый", width=8, command=lambda: self.set_color("green"))
        green_btn.grid(row=0, column=2)

        blue_btn = Button(self, text="Синий", width=8, command=lambda: self.set_color("blue"))
        blue_btn.grid(row=0, column=3)

        black_btn = Button(self, text="Чёрный", width=8, command=lambda: self.set_color("black"))
        black_btn.grid(row=0, column=4)

        white_btn = Button(self, text="Белый", width=8, command=lambda: self.set_color("white"))
        white_btn.grid(row=0, column=5)

        #clear_btn = Button(self, text="Очистить", width=8, command=lambda: self.canv.delete("all"))
        #clear_btn.grid(row=0, column=6, sticky=W)

        size_lab = Label(self, text="Размер кисти: ")
        size_lab.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5)

        one_btn = Button(self, text="2", width=8, command=lambda: self.set_brush_size(2))
        one_btn.grid(row=1, column=1)

        two_btn = Button(self, text="5", width=8, command=lambda: self.set_brush_size(5))
        two_btn.grid(row=1, column=2)

        five_btn = Button(self, text="7", width=8, command=lambda: self.set_brush_size(7))
        five_btn.grid(row=1, column=3)

        seven_btn = Button(self, text="10", width=8, command=lambda: self.set_brush_size(10))
        seven_btn.grid(row=1, column=4)

        ten_btn = Button(self, text="20", width=8, command=lambda: self.set_brush_size(20))
        ten_btn.grid(row=1, column=5)

def importImage():

    global paint
    fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Изображения", "*.jpeg;*.jpg;*.png;*.gif")])

    if fname is not None:
        try:
           img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(fname))
           paint.canv.background = img
           paint.canv.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=img)
        except Exception as err:
            messagebox.showerror("Ошибка загрузки файла", err)
    # Функция импорта изображения на холст


def saveImg():
    global paint

    fname = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension=".jpg", filetypes=[("JPEG", ".jpg")])
    if fname is None:
        return

    x = paint.canv.winfo_rootx() + 2
    y = paint.canv.winfo_rooty() + 2
    xx = x + paint.canv.winfo_width() - 4
    yy = y + paint.canv.winfo_height() - 4
    ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(x, y, xx, yy)).save(fname)
    # Функция сохранения нарисованного на холсте

def main():

    global paint
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Analoque ImageEditor')
    root.geometry("850x650+250+50")
    # Создание окна, смена его названия, размера и положения

    mainmenu = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=mainmenu)

    filemenu = Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=0)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Очистить холст", command=lambda: paint.canv.delete("all"))
    filemenu.add_command(label="Импорт", command=importImage)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Сохранить нарисованное", command=saveImg)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Выход", command=root.quit)

    helpmenu = Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=0)
    helpmenu.add_command(label="Помощь")
    helpmenu.add_command(label="О программе")

    mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Файл", menu=filemenu)
    mainmenu.add_cascade(label="Справка", menu=helpmenu)
    # Добавление меню и его дальнейшее наполнение с подменю


    paint = Paint(root)
    # Функция, открывающая возможность рисовать

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

    # Основа, которая запускает main(), если данный файл является
    # главным в запуске
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример

```
frame=Frame(r,width=300,height=300)
frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH) #.grid(row=0,column=0)

c=Canvas(frame,bg=cbg,width=600,height=400,scrollregion=(-10000,-10000,10000,10000))
c.pack()
hbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=HORIZONTAL)
hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
hbar.config(command=c.xview)
vbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=VERTICAL)
vbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
vbar.config(command=c.yview)
c.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
c.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True,fill=BOTH)
```

Comment: помечу как ответ, проверю позже. если появятся проблемы, то вернусь. но спасибо за пример, думаю, это хоть как-то поможет)